# Java: reading configuration: Unable to create lock manager

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting following error. I have Eclipse Mars and JRE V 1.7 (i initially had installed V1.8 but as it was not compatible so uninstalled and installed this version.)

I am facing this issue when invoking Eclipse itself.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-07-14 11:20:39.006
!MESSAGE Error reading configuration: Unable to create lock manager.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to create lock manager.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getChildStorageManager(Storage.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getInfoInputStream(Storage.java:1767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: Did you install Eclipse to Program Files, or other special location? Eclipse can be run from a shared location on Windows, but it takes work. My advice is to install it to your home directory.

Comment: I placed it on C:\Eclipse\eclipse and executed exe from this location.

Comment: Permissions issues are legion on Windows, because of the way ACLs can complicate things. Try installing it to your home directory to rule out permissions problems. Even if you are an "admin" user you may not actually have full control over C:\.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you don't have to correct write permissions for whatever folder eclipse is trying to write it's lock file to.  Make sure you have the correct permissions to write.

******TAKEN FROM COMMENTS******

In addition, you may also need to run Eclipse itself with administrative privileges.  For instance, in Windows, right-click -> Run as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for reverting back. I do have administrator rights on this machine.

Comment: @Shantanu Have you tried running eclipse with administrator privileges? For instance, on Windows, right-click -> Run as administrator